# Why does socket.io call get cancelled in Capacitor app on Android

Tags: android, ionic-framework, https, socket.io, capacitor

I'm trying to build an app which would stream video through a local network. I've run into an issue where all the request to `https://192.168.0.100:6873/socket.io/whatever` get the status `(cancelled)`, which is not very helpful. I get no other errors, neither CORS nor SSL.
What does that even mean? I assume the front-end decides at some point, it's not gonna call that?
It's my first time ever with Ionic / Android development, so I'm probably missing something obvious. Any help will be appreciated!

I've updated the CORS config on the server like with

```
      'capacitor://localhost',
      'ionic://localhost',
      'http://localhost',
      'https://localhost',
      'https://192.168.0.101', // phone's ip over wifi
```

---

Here's the server portion of `capacitor.config.ts`:

```
  server: {
    hostname: "localhost",
    androidScheme: "https",
    url: "localhost",
    cleartext: true,
    allowNavigation: [
      "https://localhost:6873/*",
      "https://192.168.0.100:6873/*" // laptop's addr
    ]
  },
```

---

`network_security_config.xml`, where `my_ca` is a folder with .pem & .p12 files

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">192.168.0.100</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">192.168.0.101</domain>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="@raw/my_ca"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```